# Can a sentence poetically end in 'si'?

Tags: ordre-des-mots, syntaxe

In English, particularly more antiquated or poetic forms, the adverb can be placed at the end.

> I love her *so*. It impresses me *so*.

Do the same rules apply in French? Can one similarly say-

> Je l'aime *si*. Ça m'impressionne *si*.

Or is the only proper way to use *tant* or *tellement*?

Answer (score 4):

No, "si" can't be used like that; with "tant" and "tellement" a continuation is needed.

- Ça m'impressionne tant/tellement que je ne sais pas quoi dire.

If you change the punctuation "tant" and "tellement" can be used  in the end, though ([ngram1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*+tant+%21&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A%20tant%20%21%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Baime%20tant%20%21%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpas%20tant%20%21%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Baimait%20tant%20%21%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20tant%20%21%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bt%27aime%20tant%20%21%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Baimais%20tant%20%21%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdirez%20tant%20%21%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bj%27aime%20tant%20%21%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsouffre%20tant%20%21%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bj%27aimais%20tant%20%21%3B%2Cc0), [ngram2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*+tellement+%21&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A%20tellement%20%21%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpas%20tellement%20%21%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20tellement%20%21%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPas%20tellement%20%21%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bressemble%20tellement%20%21%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Baime%20tellement%20%21%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bt%27aime%20tellement%20%21%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2C*%20tellement%20!%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpas%20tellement%20!%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20tellement%20!%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPas%20tellement%20!%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bressemble%20tellement%20!%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Baime%20tellement%20!%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bt'aime%20tellement%20!%3B%2Cc0), [ngram3](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*+tant%E2%80%A6&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A%20tant%20...%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpas%20tant%20...%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bde%20tant%20...%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Baime%20tant%20...%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Baimait%20tant%20...%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bet%20tant%20...%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20tant%20...%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bj%27aime%20tant%20...%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bt%27aime%20tant%20...%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPas%20tant%20...%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%A0%20tant%20...%3B%2Cc0)).

- Ça m'impressionne tant !
- Ça m'impressionne tant…
- Je l'aime tant !
- Ils en voient tellement…
- Elle le veut tellement !

When placed in the end, as shown above, "tant" and "tellement" receive usually a special intonation (pronunciation with more strength and special intonation).

Comment: Merci! So I guess my last question would be, which form is more idiomatic vs which form is more formal/literary – I'm assuming 'trop' would be more idiomatic, vs 'tant/tellement' slightly more accentuated?

Comment: @DrAcmeIsme The forms I added belong to the standard language : they are used both in speaking and in writing; they are not to be compared with "trop", as used that way "trop" is young people's language; its use is not recorded in the  [Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/trop/79951) and I don't recommend using it that way either, unless it is necessary to reproduce some youth's speech. Yes, you are right, "tant" and "tellement" receive special intonation in the end, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I assume that the special intonation of _tant_ could also sound ironic or sarcastic in certain contexts?

Comment: @DrAcmeIsme No doubt, sarcastic intonations too ! That might let  you presume of the variety there is to be found in this domain…It's necessary to do as much listening as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Good translation of your sentences is more like:

> Je l'aime *trop*. Ça m'impressione *trop*.

`si` cannot be used at the end of a sentence.

Comment: That is rather colloquial, and used primarily by young peuple. Not the kind of poetic usage the OP is after.